# OS ruby labs/ PATH installation problems

Tags: ruby, macos, path, rubygems, rvm

I am supposed to install ruby labs on my computer and the instructions given to me are found here: http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~conery/eic/software.html

However, I'm facing problems downloading the ruby labs gem. The command given was: 
`gem install --user-install rubylabs -n .`

I keep receiving these errors:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Users/Admin/.gem/ruby/1.8 directory.

I then did `sudo gem install --user-install rubylabs -n .`

But i got this error instead:
Successfully installed rubylabs-0.9.8 
Installing ri documentation for rubylabs-0.9.8 
/Users/Admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/Users/Admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block

Furthermore, after proceeding on with `ruby lab-setup.rb`, when I type irb, i receive this error as well: no such file to load -- rubylabs

=============================== 
Apparently it was my RVM that was causing the problem and deleting it solved the above problem. However, I would like to understand why RVM cause those issues.

Could someone please help? I'm at my wits end.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue as well:

```
no such file to load -- rubylabs
```

`ruby lab-setup.rb` basically adds lines to require rubygems and rubylabs on each new IRB session. The above `no such file to load` basically meant that `rubylabs` is not installed locally in rvm. A `gem list` command would reveal something like the following:

```
MBA:~ user$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
```

I am new to Ruby as well... So what I did was basically just run the following command to install `rubylabs`:

```
gem install rubylabs -n .
```

A `gem list` would reveal it as installed:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
rake (10.1.1)
rubygems-test (0.4.3)
rubylabs (0.9.8)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
```

IRB will now run normally.